# How to sort hierarchically multidimensional Array by level

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, logic

I need to sort an array hierarchically by level column.

I extract this data from HTML headers (h1, h2, h3 ...) and need to organize them hierarchically in an array. Basically this will be used to display a "Table of Contents".

** Edited **

```
// The soluction (Thanks @trincot)
static public function build_hierarchy( &$links, $level = 1 ) {
    
    $result = [];
    while (current($links)) {
        if ( current($links)["level"] > $level ) {
           $result[ count($result)-1 ]["children"] = static::build_hierarchy($links, $level+1);
        }
        if (current($links)["level"] < $level ) return $result; // backtrack
        $result[] = current($links);
        next($links);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I have the following Array:

```
     Array(
            [0] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '1', 
                    'id' => 'item 1', 
                    'content' => 'item 1'
            ),
            [1] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '1', 
                    'id' => 'item 2', 
                    'content' => 'item 2'
            ),
            [2] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '2', 
                    'id' => 'item 3', 
                    'content' => 'item 3'
            ),
            [3] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '2', 
                    'id' => 'item 4', 
                    'content' => 'item 4'
            ),
            [4] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '2', 
                    'id' => 'item 5', 
                    'content' => 'item 5'
            ),
            [5] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '3', 
                    'id' => 'item 6', 
                    'content' => 'item 6'
            ),
            [6] =  Array( 
                    'level' => '1', 
                    'id' => 'item 7', 
                    'content' => 'item 7'
            ),  

        )
```

I need output (By level column):

```
Array(
    [0] =  Array( 
            'level' => '1', 
            'id' => 'item 1', 
            'content' => 'item 1'   
        ),
    [1] =  Array( 
            'level' => '1', 
            'id' => 'item 2', 
            'content' => 'item 2',
            'childrens' => Array(
                [0] = Array(
                    'level' => '2', 
                    'id' => 'item 3', 
                    'content' => 'item 3'
                ),
                [1] = Array(
                    'level' => '2', 
                    'id' => 'item 4', 
                    'content' => 'item 4'
                ),
                [2] = Array(
                    'level' => '2', 
                    'id' => 'item 5', 
                    'content' => 'item 5',
                    'childrens' => Array(
                        [0] = Array(
                            'level' => '3', 
                            'id' => 'item 6', 
                            'content' => 'item 6'
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        ),
    [2] =  Array( 
        'level' => '1', 
        'id' => 'item 7', 
        'content' => 'item 7'   
    )
)
```

I can not do this! I need your help.

### ** Update 1: **

I can not flow with the logic of it! I've been trying for two days! I don't know how to go **from level 3 to level 1** for example, this seems impossible!

Comment: In a nutshell, going through the array in order, when you encounter a *deeper* level, you add a child array, when you encounter the same level, you keep adding to the current array, and when you encounter a higher level you go back up, correct?

Comment: @deceze Right! But how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you don't distinguish between a level that increases or decreases. Yet the action to take would be completely different. In the first case you need to recurse, in the other you need to immediately backtrack (return)

I would also suggest to not mutate the array that is passed to the function, but to produce a new array. This is more *functional programming* style.

Here is how I would write it:

```
function build_hierarchy(&$links, $level = 1) {
    $result = [];
    while (current($links)) {
        if (current($links)["level"] > $level ) {
            $result[max(0, count($result)-1)]["children"] = build_hierarchy($links, $level+1);
        }
        if (current($links)["level"] < $level ) return $result; // backtrack
        $result[] = current($links);
        next($links);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I'm having problems when the level starts with a number other than 1 or it starts from level 1 and the next level is 3 for example. It displays "[-1] => [-1] ..." in these cases. I tried to change your code but I did not succeed. My solution is to make a foreach and remove the "-1", but this does not seem to be ideal.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be92a494f91e7ffc4dab0d2d820b0068b89c0ec7

Comment: Yes, but what *do* you want to happen in those cases? Could you edit your question and add examples with both scenarios? For instance, if the level starts with 2, but ends with 1, then what should happen? Or, if there is a jump from 1 to 3, but then a 2. What should the resulting data structure look like?

Comment: Would it be what you want when `count($result)-1` is replaced with `max(0, count($result)-1)`?

Comment: the result is something like:

 [0] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
   'children' => Array(
    'level' => '3', 
    'id' => 'item 3', 
    'content' => 'item 3'
   );
  ) 
 )

Comment: Yes, but I am more interested in seeing what you *expect* for such cases. Could you update your question with an example like described in my previous comment? The intermediate `[0]` element without other data is just a stub to indicate "here is a missing level 2 -- I have no data to show here".

Comment: I am really curious how you would want the data structure to look in those cases? Like when the sequence of levels is 3, 5, 1, 4, 2.... Could you add such case in your question together with the expected output for it?

Comment: So this is a TOC. The user can insert an H1 tag and then an H3 tag, not entirely sure, but should be predicted. The h1 (level 1) tag is just below the H3 (level 3) tag, I expected that. I preferred to keep the result as "-1" because so I can check whether it is "empty" or not ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. It took me 2 days to solve it and you made it seem like something easy :)